# How to find connection between sequence and formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

I have one sequence, which is defined like this:

```
4,7,10,12,15,17,20,22,24
```

I also found it at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C7%2C10%2C12%2C15%2C17%2C20%2C22%2C24&language=english&go=Search).

And there they have a formula, which I can use to find minimal number of matches to complete squares:

```
2*n+ceil(2*sqrt(n))
```

It works fine. But I have no clue how to come from this sequence to formula. Is there any obvious steps which one should attempt?

I also had an assumption that if we are building squares in 1D formula is:

```
3*n+1
```

For to 2D I thought formula should be related to squaring somehow(square root is related to squaring but it was not what I expected) and for 3D - cubing. Looks I'm wrong.

Comment: That one would be difficult to spot just from the sequence of numbers. If the numbers arose from a specific problem, however, the problem itself might give the necessary insight.

Comment: If you need to implement computer algorithm for it, how would you start?

Comment: Computer algorithm for what? Displaying a minimal arrangement of sticks that produces $n$ squares?

Comment: Yes. I started with finding formula for this sequence. But found it only on OEIS. I can try to write some loops which will generate those numbers. But as I can see formula is the best solution in this case.

Comment: The formula is the quickest way to get the numbers themselves. The arrangements can be built in a sort of zig-zag pattern, in the order illustrated below for the first $16$ squares. This arrangement should also give you an idea of where the formula comes from. $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
1&2&9&10\\ \hline
4&3&8&11\\ \hline
5&6&7&12\\ \hline
16&15&14&13\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, it helps to see/know the first differences are either 2 or 3, presuming that continues.  That allows one to obtain the "2n" portion requiring an yet-to-be determined subsequent adjustment.
This presumes n=1,2,3 ... where we can see using 3n for n=6 exceeds 17, giving us 2n.
So our baseline is 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18.
We need to map these base values to your 4,7,10,12,15,17,20,22,24.
A quick glimpse of the discrepancies vs n chart shows it increases with n, but is not strictly monotonic.  Additionally, the numerical discrepancy is seen to include both above and below n, so if it is a function of n, it is reductive (like a root or log).
From the image you can then see how one might play around in a spreadsheet.  Here we see col D=col G for the limited dataset.

[image]